# \listoftables with large captions does not break page

Tags: table-of-contents, vertical-alignment

People I have a horrendously large style file .... I know you will beat me up if I add it again so please see it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196730/tabularx-missing-number-treated-as-zero-error).

so this time the problem is that some of my tables have very large captions (like 10-20 lines large) so in the `\listoftables` generated List of Tables I am sometimes getting only two captions in one page as latex can not fit the next caption there, so the gap between the two captions in one page is going very high. I would like the caption going to the next page to break in two pages to solve this problem so that the gap between two table entries remains the same everywhere.

I am in the biggest hurry ever in my life .... my thesis is due to the printers tomorrow morning .... :(

Comment: if it is permitted to use shorter captions in the list of tables, you should make use of the optional argument to `\caption`.  this will result in a much more usable list of tables as well as one that looks better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

many document classes support the use of an optional argument to `\caption`
to provide a short form for the list of tables or list of figures:

```
\caption[short version]{very long and detailed explanatory caption
  to be set with the table or figure}
```

for those document classes that don't offer this possibility (for example, the ams classes), a possible strategy is to put only the most necessary text
in the caption itself, and set the additional material in a block of text
below the caption, in a type size matching that of the caption.
narrowing this block of text, say by using the `quotation` environment,
could be worth a try.